# zend framework - quickstart application

Tags: zend-framework

I have been attempting to install the 'quickstart' tutorial application on my system. After a considerable amount of frustration - a) because I dont know how it all works andb) mine's a windows (wamp) set-up, I have got as far as setting up the guestbook database successfully and reaching the Checkpoint:
Now browse to http://localhost/guestbook. You should see the following in your browser:

I get error:
Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\quickstart\application/models//GuestbookMapper.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\quickstart\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader\Resource.php on line 176

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\wamp\www\quickstart\application/models//GuestbookMapper.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www\quickstart\library;.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR;C:\wamp\zend\library;C:\wamp\zend\extras\library') in C:\wamp\www\quickstart\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader\Resource.php on line 176

Fatal error: Class 'Default_Model_GuestbookMapper' not found in C:\wamp\www\quickstart\application\models\Guestbook.php on line 102

Obviously failing to link relevant files is the main issue - 
First, that 'C:\wamp\www\quickstart\application/models//GuestbookMapper.php' looks wrong to me, but I cant figure out what's creating it. Second, I have a very tenuous grip on the whole file path system and cant tell whether things are wrongly configured. If I could  get the guestbook app to function, then I might be able to get a grip on what's going on. As it is, I seem to fix one problem only to find another round the next corner.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file for the directory style, maybe it's set to the wrong type (you have an option between Win32 and Unix).

Comment: I checked that out but the only php.ini options are for setting the include_path. I have it set forwindows and it works fine for everything else. that 'quickstart\application/models//GuestbookMapper.php' doesnt look right, but it may well be. The fact remains that guestbookMapper.php wont open from quickstart\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader\Resource.php but I dont know how to alter it

Answer (score 0):

OK - fixed it! GuestbookMapper was in the wrong directory - the path was right -the file just wasn't there. I still cant get my mind around this directory structure , I hope it dawns on me eventually...